# Maven deploy Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not find artifact

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy a maven app on elastic beanstalk, and I'm following this guide https://aws.amazon.com/pt/blogs/developer/deploying-java-applications-on-elastic-beanstalk-from-maven/.

However when i run the `mvn -Ps3-deploy package deploy` command I get an error saying `Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not find artifact Timzudo:MinguitoOnline:jar:1 in 20278788 (https://gitlab.com/Msgouveia/ok.git)`.

I don't really understand why this is happening since the repo is public and the project that is there has the same groupId, artifactId, version, and packaging.

Info and distributionManagement:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>Timzudo</groupId>
<artifactId>MinguitoOnline</artifactId>
<version>1</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>Java Sample Jetty App</name>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
      <id>20278788</id>
      <name>MinguitoOnline</name>
      <url>https://gitlab.com/Msgouveia/ok.git</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Comment: The tutorial is for EB platform based on Amazon Linux 1. Are you using AL1 or Amazon Linux 2?

Comment: From the error it seems to me that you need to build a sub-project. I vaguely remember a similar case that I had, but I'm not sure that I remember it correctly, so I will avoid writing an answer for now.

Comment: I don't quite get it. `distributionManagement` expects a Maven repository, and you seem to be providing a **GIT** URL.

Comment: I'm probably wrong but shouldn't i provide the git url of the project? If it expects a maven repository, wich one should it be? Sorry if i don't understand enough about this.